Error when using EOR instruction in assembly on mac M1
I'm having an issue using the eor instruction in assembly on my Mac M1. For example:
.global _start
.align 2

_start:
    mov X1, #0
    eor X0, X1, #0x5
    mov X16, #1
    svc #0x80

When I assemble this code, I get the following error:
as bitwise_XOR.s -o bitwise_XOR.o
bitwise_XOR.s:6:17: error: expected compatible register or logical immediate
    eor X0, X1, #0x5

I encounter the same issue when replacing 0x5 with values like 0x0, 0x9, 0xA and many others values , but it works for 0x1, 0x2, 0x6, and others. I don’t understand why it works for some numbers but not for others. I've also tried changing the register where the value is stored, but I still get the same error.
Can someone explain what's going wrong?
